Is sparse RBF kernel necessarily PSD?
We know that RBF kernel is PSD, now, suppose that instead of computing $\exp\frac{|x_i-x_j|^2}{\sigma^2}$ for all pairs, I compute it for only for similiar data-points in order to achieve a sparse kernel matrix.
Suppose I'm doing something like this:
$K(i,j)=
\begin{cases}
 \exp\frac{|x_i-x_j|^2}{\sigma^2}&\text{if}\, |x_i-x_j|\leq c_0\\
 0&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$
So this way I can get a sparse $K$ for a fixed threshold $c_0$, the question is that is $K$ necessarily spare in this case? My code experiments shows it's not, however I'm not sure this is because of a bug in my code or it's a theoretical thing. If it is still PSD, can you show me a snippet for that?

It will typically not be positive definite after this truncation. One previous version of this question is here

We can't comment on code that you haven't shared, but in any case, questions about debugging are not on-topic here.

Answering the titular question -- truncating small values will not, in general, produce a PSD result. Instead, what you're looking for is a kernel function with compact support. These are discussed on page 88 of Rasmussen & Williams and also in Wendland.
Wendland, H. (2005). Scattered Data Approximation. Cambridge Monographs on Applied and Computational Mathematics. Cambridge University Press. p. 88
Williams, Christopher KI, and Carl Edward Rasmussen. Gaussian processes for machine learning. Vol. 2. No. 3. Cambridge, MA: MIT press, 2006.

(+1) Mentioning compact support is very useful. Feel a bit thick for not mentioning it. Didn't see the answer afterwards.

@usεr11852 Happens to all of us. That's why I like the collaborative nature of the site -- in the best case, allowing multiple answers allows multiple views on a topic.

Sparsity and positive definiteness rarely play along.
There are a number of non-necessary situations that make these to matrix properties not too nice with each other.

A PD matrix is full rank. A sparse matrix, can be full rank but as the sparseness increases the chance of rank deficiency as we literally have more cells with the same value ($0$). In fairness, when working with diagonally dominant matrices we are more likely to have a P(S)D matrix but we are playing a dangerous game when that diagonal dominance is due to sparsity.
Thinking of positive semi-definiteness as a relating to the "matrix having a square root" and in particular the less used definition of the square root of a matrix pertaining in having a Cholesky decomposition $LL^T$. For a matrix cell to be sparse, i.e. numerically zero, we need the dot product of a row from $L$ and a column from $L^T$ to equal $0$. That means in a dot product $x^Ty$, we want $\sum_{k}^N x_{jk}y_{ik} = 0$, but likely we need $\sum_{k}^N x_{jk}y_{(i+1)k} \neq 0$. That is of course perfectly possible, but it immediately constraints our problem massively.
In a similar concept as the point for $LL^T$: for a matrix to be P(S)D the non-zero entries must still be such that all principal minors (i.e. determinants of top-left submatrices) remain non-negative. As we introduce sparsity, we reduce the degrees of freedom to meet that requirement.
Positive (semi-)definite matrices form a convex cone within the space of symmetric matrices. This convex cone is closed under positive scalar multiplication and linear combinations of positive definite matrices, meaning that any non-negative linear combination of positive definite matrices remains positive definite. However, inducing sparsity cannot generally be achieved through simple scaling or linear transformations.

With the above being said, I hope it is clear that while possible to impose some arbitrary degree of sparseness to a P(S)D matrix and that matrix to remain P(S)D, it is somewhat unlikely that it will remain P(S)D afterwards. We likely need to solve a rather involved optimisation problem to induce sparseness. That said, for "real-world application" most likely our full kernel matrix also has some $\sigma_{noise}I$ term too, that term can act as a regulariser to ensure diagonal dominance and thus P(S)D for the overall kernal matrix $K$.
